# Writing a function which returns a modified list with ! after every item in a list

Tags: python, list, function

so I've ran into a road block trying to write a function which takes a single parameter , a list and the function should return a modified list which adds a '!' after the end of each item in the list. So this is what I have so far :

```
def add_enthusiasm_to_list(list):

    new_list = []
    for i in list:
        enthusiasm = i + '!'
        new_list.append(enthusiasm)
        return(new_list)

print(add_enthusiasm_to_list(['hi', 'hello']))

print(add_enthusiasm_to_list(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

But so far I can only get the first item of each list , so my output would be

['hi!'] for the first one and

['a!'] for the second one.

What would be the best way for me to modify it so that each item in the list gets returned with an exclamation point at the end? 
Thanks!

Comment: You to `return` the new list, **_only at the very end of your function_**. By returning `new_list` in the middle of the `for` loop, you're only allow one item to be added to `new_list`, before returning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `return` once you are done with the `for` loop.
Like this:

```
def add_enthusiasm_to_list(list):

    new_list = []
    for i in list:
        enthusiasm = i + '!'
        new_list.append(enthusiasm)
    return(new_list)

print(add_enthusiasm_to_list(['hi', 'hello']))

print(add_enthusiasm_to_list(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Notice how the `return` is indented so that it is at the end of the `for` loop in your function. If you don't do this, the function will return as soon as the `for` loop executes for your first `i` in `list`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It was driving me a little insane and it has shown me to check for my indents properly right now.

Comment: You had the indentation wrong in the body of the function, probably from a simple pasting-into-SO problem. (And of course that problem only comes up when you're answering a question that's actually about indentation…)

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out the syntax error, but here is a way to do the same using list comprehension:

```
new_list = [x + "!" for x in my_list]
```

Or as a function:

```
def add_enthusiasm_to_list(my_list):
    return [x + "!" for x in my_list]
```

Also, don't name your variable `list`. Though it's limited to the scope of your function in your example, it's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get the format that you are looking for:

```
def add_enthusiasm_to_list(list):
        '''
        Model a function that adds !
        to the end of a list item
        '''

        new_list = []
        for i in list:
             i = i + '!'
             new_list.append(i)

        return new_list
```

print(add_enthusiasm_to_list(['hi', 'hello']))

print(add_enthusiasm_to_list(['a', 'b', 'c']))

Here is the output:

```
['hi!', 'hello!']
['a!', 'b!', 'c!']
```

1. We create the function as you already did, passing list as the param.
2. I created an empty list called new_list, just like you did.
3. I created the for loop, which iterates over each item in the list (i), and list is the parameter(the list that we will pass as an arg).
4. I change the value of i (the list item) to i + "!". You named the variable i enthusiasm, which works fine. You can keep that. I append each instance of (i) to the new_list, and then finally return to new_list outside of the loop, so that when you execute the function, you will get a fully formatted list with the !(enthusiasm) at the end that you are looking for. The difference that I see between my code and your code is that you returned the newly formatted list within the for loop, which I would assume means it only iterated over the first item in the list, and then returned, without returning the entire list. Shifting the return statement outside of the for loop appears to be your only issue.